# mod_rewrite seems to be ignoring condition statements

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirection

I'm dying on this htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[www\.]?old\.com [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.+$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdomain  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from www.old.com to www.new.com EXCEPT when they access:

```
www.old.com
old.com
old.com/wp-admin
old.com/subdomain
```

I still want the old site to show up and be able to administer it, but any `old.com/something` should be redirected to `new.com/something`.

That's the other thing, I couldn't get this to work by using `$1` as a backreference. I had to hard-code the `%{REQUEST_URI}` in there instead (which worked).

The last exmaple (`old.com/subdomain`) is a second website entirely and I don't want to interfere with its operation either.

I've read so, so many websites and every variation makes perfect sense from a regular expression point of view and they all should work, but they don't. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(wp-admin|index|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: No change of any kind. Also I want to be able to visit www.old.com and see the parked page I put there while only redirecting to the new when they try to access www.new.com/anything_except_wpadmin_or_index.php

Comment: @user77914: I made a minor correction, please try again. Also if you notice I am only redirecting `.+` which means `http://www.old.com` will NOT be redirected to `http://www.new.com`.

Comment: It still redirects all requests for old.com to new.com. I'm starting to think there's some other issue at hand here, but I've commented out nearly every other line in the file except for RewriteEngine on, RewriteBase /, Options +FollowSymLinks, and the few lines Wordpress adds for pretty permalinks.

Comment: **Just for testing** comment both the RewriteCond lines and have your RewriteRule like this `RewriteRule ^(wp-admin)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]`
. That should start redirecting ONLY wp-admin but leave everything else as is.